# Como puedo obtener las estadísticas de Google Developers Console de mi aplicación de Play Store de manera programática

Tags: python, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-services

He visto que no hay API para consumir los datos de descargas, reseñas...

Necesito extraer la misma info que aparece en el Dashboard de Google Developers Console.

Los datos de la API de la Analytics no me sirven.

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta parece ser "demasiado amplia" tu pregunta, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Provee más detalles. Como @Elenasys menciona, tienes una pregunta "demasiado amplia", y no podemos ayudarte con eso. Edita tu pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico.

Answer (score 0):

para las reseñas y las respuesta de las mismas, si exite.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews

Avisa si encontraste alguna forma de obtener los otros datos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).